# How to find area of difference between 2 bitmaps using Renderscript?

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

I have 2 bitmaps of exactly the same size and I want to find the smallest area of change between the two. Here's a Kotlin equivalent of what I am doing:

```
var minX = Int.MAX_VALUE
var minY = Int.MAX_VALUE
var maxX = 0
var maxY = 0

for (i in 0 until cols) {
    for (j in 0 until rows) {
        if (bitmapOne.getPixel(i, j) != bitmapTwo.getPixel(i, j)) {
            if (i < minX) minX = i
            if (i > maxX) maxX = i
            if (j < minY) minY = j
            if (j > maxY) maxY = j
        }
    }
}
```

All I need is the four points of rectangle holding the smallest area of change. Renderscript bitmap iterations are way faster based on some tests I did, so I am trying to learn Renderscript and port this Kotlin code too.

The issue I am facing is that I am unable to pass 2 bitmaps as allocations 
to any mapping kernel. The documentation says

> "If you need more input or output Allocations than the kernel has,
>   those objects should be bound to rs_allocation script globals and
>   accessed from a kernel or invokable function via rsGetElementAt_type()
>   or rsSetElementAt_type()."

But there are not enough examples around this.

The second issue is how to get a return type, since none of the kernels have a return type - the input/output allocation examples I see so far are all of same dimensions. But I need a different dimension as output (just an Int4).

On going through the reduce kernel documentation, it seems like they too can't process 2 allocations together.

I may be wrong in my understanding so far. Would appreciate any help which can get me started.

Answer (score 2):

Script globals will definitely help solve your situation.  Essentially, they are script variables which the Java/Kotlin side can access to set or get.  If you are able to use Android 7+ only, you could do this as a reduction kernel (rather than a mapping kernel).  Basically, there's no "output" allocation.

Here's a quick write up of doing this via mapping kernel.  I've not tried or compiled this, so you may have to tweak it.  Assuming you have your two `Bitmap` objects and they are the same size/format (no error handling here to keep it short), and are working in an `Activity`, you could set it up like this:

```
//  You should only create the Rendescript context and script one
//  time in the lifetime of your Activity.  It is an expensive op.
Renderscript rs = Renderscript.create(this);
ScriptC_diffBitmap script = new ScriptC_diffBitmap(rs);

Allocation inAlloc1 =
    Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs,
                                bitmap1,
                                Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
Allocation inAlloc2 =
    Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs,
                                bitmap2,
                                Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createTyped(rs,
                                             inAlloc2.getType());
script.set_maxX(0);
script.set_maxY(0);
script.set_minX(Int.MAX_VALUE);
script.set_minY(Int.MAX_VALUE);
script.set_inBitmap1(inAlloc1);
script.foreach_root(inAlloc2, outAlloc);

//  Get back the min/max values and do whatever you need
minX = script.get_minX();
minY = script.get_minY();
maxX = script.get_maxX();
maxY = script.get_mayY();
```

The Rendescript code to support this (again, using a *mapping kernel*), named `diffBitmap.rs`:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.DiffBitmap)

int32_t minX;
int32_t minY;
int32_t maxX;
int32_t maxY;
rs_allocation inBitmap1;

uchar4 RS_KERNEL root(uchar4 inBitmap2Point, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    uchar4 inBitmap1Point = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inBitmap1, x, y);

    if ((inBitmap1Point.r != inBitmap2Point.r) ||
        (inBitmap1Point.g != inBitmap2Point.g) ||
        (inBitmap1Point.b != inBitmap2Point.b) ||
        (inBitmap1Point.a != inBitmap2Point.a))
    {
        if (x < minX) minX = x;
        if (x > maxX) maxX = x;
        if (y < minY) minY = y;
        if (y > maxY) maxY = y;
    }

    //  Since we have to return an output, just return bitmap1
    return inBitmap1Point;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. But can you please try compiling it? The first line in the root() function is causing an error as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074004/renderscript-not-matching-function-rsgetelementat-uchar4. I am unable to use the proposed solution because unless the script compiles and Java stub is created, I dont get access to the allocation setter. I have tried building with renderscriptTargetApi 24 and 26.

Comment: Why do we use a uchar4 variable with the same name as rs_allocation (inBitmap1)? Wouldn't that confuse the compiler whenever we use inBitmap1? I tried changing the function variable uchar 4 from inBitmap1 to temp, but compilation failed in the if condition with error "statement requires expression of scalar type. vector of 4 'char' values invalid"

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo on my part and the `if` check was just a quick and dirty attempt from memory.  Adjusted above, try that.

Comment: It compiles now, but returns the min/max values as defined originally. I assume rsForEach calls are async in nature, so I also added rs.finish() before using getters in the Java code. Still no luck. For test I am using a plain red image from the web (bitmap1) and adding a small green rectangle at center using image editing tools (bitmap2)

Comment: Yeah, you may need to call `finish()` for the script before calling the getters for the script variables.  You will likely need to add some instrumentation via [rsDebug](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_debug.html#android_rs:rsDebug) calls to see what is going on.  Just be sure to remove them before you ship as that call has a huge impact on performance.

Comment: Will debug for now. If I find a working solution, I will update your answer and mark it resolved. Thanks!